# ROR unit test error: SyntaxError: (erb):18:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I have a ROR project and all the unit tests are failing with the same error as listed below. To figure out the cause I created an empty test case, the code is follows.

```
require 'test_helper'
class UsersEditTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "the truth" do
    assert true
  end
end
```

When the run the test with "rake test TEST=test/integration/users_edit_test.rb" command I get the following error

```
1) Error:
  UsersEditTest#test_the_truth:
  SyntaxError: (erb):18: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
  ;  end ; _erbout.force_encoding(__ENCODING__)
  ^   

1 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

Not sure what is missing in the project, I have other test projects where unit tests just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably not connected to tests, you have error in view (erb file).
Check if everything is ok in views, especially `<%=` tags

Comment: That was my first thought – However, there are no erb files in the project. All the view/html are haml files.